# How to import and use data from JSON which is object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Previously i import data from JSON wihch was a Array, that wasn't a problem. Now i have a problem because my variable is an object. I want to push all the questions into the array and then make them visible on the html document.
The link to JSON file is on the code.

And JS code.

```js
const myjson = 'http://tnij.xyz/bj5'; // LINK TO JSON FILE!
const questions = [];
fetch(myjson)
    .then(blob => blob.json('questions'))
    .then(data => questions.push(data))

console.log(questions);
```

Comment: `.then(data => data.object.property)` will reveal the value of `property`.

Comment: Yes ! It is working. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

(NOTE: I couldn't run the snippet because of a cross-origin issues)

I think what you need to do is either `.concat` the incoming values or use `.apply`. Personally, I'd go for `.concat`:

```js
const myjson = 'http://tnij.xyz/bj5'; // LINK TO JSON FILE!
const questions = [];
fetch(myjson)
    .then(blob => blob.json('questions'))
    .then(data => {
        questions = quest.concat(data);
        console.info(questions);
    });
```

Also remember that `questions` is going to be empty outside of the `fetch` chain.

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- As http://tnij.xyz/bj5 returns the object having property as `questions` which is an `array` then why again you want to push it into an array **?**
- You can directly access the questions array using `jsonObj.questions`.Here, `jsonObj` is whole JSON object that you are getting in response.
- You can append questions and answers in the HTML like this **:**

```js
var questions = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "Obwód trójkąta ABC wynosi 20cm. Jaką długość ma podstawa AB?",
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "answer": "8.4 cm",
          "correct": true
        },
        
        {
          "id": 2,
          "answer": "5.8 cm",
          "correct": false
        },
        
        {
          "id": 1,
          "answer": "0.6 cm",
          "correct": false
        },
        
        {
          "id": 1,
          "answer": "1.2 cm",
          "correct": false
        }
      ]
    }];
    
for(var i in questions) {
  document.getElementById('questions').innerHTML = questions[i].question;
  var answers = document.getElementById("answers");
  for(var j in questions[i].answers) {
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var radio = document.createElement("input");
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.name = "choices";
    radio.value = questions[i].answers[j].correct;
    label.appendChild(radio);
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(questions[i].answers[j].answer));
    answers.appendChild(label);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="questions">
</div>
<div id="answers"></div>
```